# Facebook Connect Registration "Undo" Popup

Tags: facebook

I m using facebook registration plugin for my site registration. when i try to click register a new window opens and shows the text quoted below. How to block this window?? Help me out.

"You've just registered for {app_name} using your Facebook account.
If you didn't mean to do this, you can undo this below."

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't block the window, it's a part of Facebook's system, not yours. Also, I'm sure if you did find a way to block it, it would be in violation of Facebook's API ToS.

Comment: If this is true, then why dont we see this on other websites.  For example, espn.com and freindfeed.com both have facebook connect.  When you connect with them, this confirmation box does not appear.  How are they doing this?